# cant use variable outside loop python

Tags: python, declaration

on running error is comming like

"name 'traverse' is not defined"

Belows the code

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(DIR):
    traverse = list(set(dirs).intersection(set(LIST)))
    break

print "Working ", traverse
print "Starting"
```

Comment: Yes, scoping. Have you tried declaring outside the loop, or printing inside?

Comment: Are you sure that at least one iteration of a cycle was done?

Comment: @cricket_007 I doubt this has anything to do with scope... and Python doesn't have declarations...

Comment: yes its iterating...

Comment: I tried declaring outside loop also

like

traverse = list()

Comment: Can You put `print('inside')` inside `for` loop and check if it really iterates? It should we working if there is at least one pass...

Comment: Can you report (in the question, otherwise will be unreadable) all the error message with all the backtrace? There is apparently no reason for your code to not working...

Comment: @Nitin
Thanks it workedd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a possibility that the loop hasn't iterated even once hence, the variable `traverse` is yet to have any value.

you can try below to check:

```
traverse =None
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(DIR):
    traverse = list(set(dirs).intersection(set(LIST)))
    break

if traverse is None:
    print("loop did not execute")
else:
    print("Working ", traverse)
```